# Program refuses to install in wine, telling me that "the operating system is not adequate"

Tags: wine

I am attempting to install a program for a class using WINE, but during installation the installer detects that it is running in an environment other than Windows 7/8/10, and refuses to install. How can I make the installer think it is running in Windows?

The program in question is [Vitalsource Bookshelf](https://support.vitalsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/201344733-Bookshelf-Download-Page), and is only available for Windoze 7/8/10, android, iOS, and OSX, and the android version does not have the features that I need for my class. When I attempt to install the program in WINE, the installer reports

```
The operating system is not adequate for running VitalSource Bookshelf.
```

[image]

Fortunately, I don't need to use it right away, but I do need to get it to work somehow.

What can I do to determine the reason the installer is rejecting WINE, and if possible, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, Win 7/8/8.1/10. In <kbd>Wine configuration</kbd>, start via <kbd>Configure Wine</kbd>, you can select 95/98/ME/2000/XP and so on and Windows 8, too. All right?

[image]

Now start the installation of Bookshelf

```
wine BookshelfSetup.exe
```

Comment: Got .NET installed, but now I get another mystery error: `File 'C:\users\anson\Temp\_is6da.tmp' can not be found. Make sure the file is on target system or installed already.` or with other  hex numbers instead of 6da on subsequent attempts.

Comment: Yes, same here... But sorry, that's another  question. **;)**

Comment: and that question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678003/installer-in-wine-cant-find-c-users-myusername-temp-is6da-tmp).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `wine1.7` to be able to configure the Windows version to a newer release than XP, I think.

To do this, first you need to add the wine PPA, then refresh the sources list, and finally install the newer *wine*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
```

Once installed, you will need to run `winecfg` and select *Windows 7* or one of the other newer versions that is required, and you should be able to install your application. However, you may still encounter other issues with it, and may need to actually run it on Windows, either directly on hardware, or in a VM.

Comment: Wine 1.6.2 (the default on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) allows you to pick Windows 7 and 8

Comment: The question was asked prior to Ubuntu 15.10 even being released.

Comment: Its not about the Ubuntu version. The answer above says minimum is wine 1.7 and i'm simply noting that the functionality exists in wine 1.6.2. (Which happens to be an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but thats besides the point.)