# Installer in WINE can't find `C:\users\myusername\Temp\_is6da.tmp`

Tags: wine

I am attempting to install a program for a class using WINE, but during installation, the installer tries to use a file in `C:\users\anson\Temp\_is6da.tmp` (or with a different string of hex digits at the end), fails to find it, and refuses to install. How can I get this program to install?

The program in question is [Vitalsource Bookshelf](https://support.vitalsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/201344733-Bookshelf-Download-Page), and is only available for Windoze 7/8/10, android, iOS, and OSX, and the android version does not have the features that I need for my class. When I attempt to install the program in WINE (set to windows 7 mode), the installer reports:

```
File 'C:\users\anson\Temp\_is6da.tmp' can not be found.
Make sure the file is on target system or installed already.
```

Subsequent attempts to install it have reported the same error, with different filenames, such as `_is5506.tmp`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing DLL `d3d10_1.dll`. You can see the error message if you start wine via terminal:

```
err:module:import_dll Library d3d10_1.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\aboettger\\Temp\\_isf61a.tmp") not found
```

Therefore search and download the DLL and place the file in `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32`

```
cp d3d10_1.dll ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32
```

and install via <kbd>Wine configuration</kbd>, start <kbd>Configure Wine</kbd>.

[image]

or use the Windows `cmd` **;)** via

```
cd ~/Downloads
wine cmd
```

and

```
copy d3d10_1.dll C:\windows\system32
regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\d3d10_1.dll
```